# My for loop contents don't get executed swift 3

Tags: for-loop, swift3

I have the following code

```
if editingStyle == .delete{
        let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Collection", message: "All expenses in this collection will also be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            let collection = self.collections[indexPath.row]
            CoreDataHelper.deleteCollection(collection: collection)

            for expense in self.collectionExpensesDelete{
                print ("deleted")
                if expense.collection! == self.collections[indexPath.row].title{
                    CoreDataHelper.deleteExpense(expense: expense)
                }
            }
            self.collections.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.collections = CoreDataHelper.retrieveCollections()
        }))
```

What I want to do is to delete all expenses associated if a collection is deleted. However the for loop in the middle, the breakpoint that I have placed on it doesn't get called. Only the initial breakpoint on the "for" statement gets called and none of the code inside get called, including the delete statement.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you populating self.collectionExpensesDelete ?I think its empty

Comment: It is populated using core data like this:    

    var collectionExpensesDelete = [Expense]() {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

Comment: I think you are only initializing with empty array of type Expense, where are you setting the values inside it , and to confirm if its empty  before for loop add print(self.collectionExpensesDelete.count) and see if it prints 0

Comment: It returns 3, but my expenses don't get deleted.

Comment: Can you please post sample data of `self.collectionExpensesDelete`

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason as to the code you posted above that the for loop should not be executed.

There is a potential issue with `expense.collection!` in your *if statement* being force unwrapped. Is this intentional? If so why are you not *guard let* of *if let* this. I could well explain why your code inside the *if statement* is not being executed.

What is `CoreDataHelper`? If it is a custom class to help manage interactions with CoreData then make sure you have properly implemented the `context.delete(object)` correctly in your  `CoreDataHelper` class.

In the `CoreDataHelper` you should be something like this:

- Fetch the record that needs to be deleted
- Mark the record for deletion
- Save the changes